# SpringBoot Security Does not Whitelist Login Endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have been trying to get a sample SpringBoot app up and running along with SpringBoot Security+JWT helping me handle the security situation. (The source code can be found here: https://github.com/vaddipar/groclist)

I have followed https://youtu.be/X80nJ5T7YpE?list=WL tutorial religiously and setup the entire SpringBoot Security configuration.

Now, I achieved half of my goal which is to add security but I am unable to whitelist the Login and Register endpoints.

My *WebSecurityConfig* is given below. It has the configuration to whitelist the login and register endpoints but it does not work. Can someone take a look and let know what is going wrong here.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a min verifiable code. I did attempt to clone your repository but got this error instead: `Cannot resolve com.groclist.groclistconverter:groclistconverter:0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use login as an endpoint along with spring security. Use authenticate or signin instead and it should work fine.

Comment: Can you please point to a documentation that supports your answer?

Comment: @Prashant I tried out the same configuration with the said endpoints and the ones in my comment seem to work fine. Do you see anything else wrong with the config posted?

Comment: I understand that your endpoints work. But that is no reason to think that the endpoints used by OP would not work. The OP has provided no debug logs to come to that conclusion. I have not personally seen any part of spring documentation that states not to use `/login` as an authentication endpoint. I was guessing if you have seen something like that in docs.

Comment: @Prashant No, I did not find anything in spring documentation to indicate the same.

Comment: @Prashant to clarify as to why I thought to actually trying a new endpoint was because Spring Security comes with an inbuilt login endpoint. So I assumed there would be a clash with the OP's endpoint and the internal endpoint and hence tried out the change.